# XML validator (checks whether given xml is correct or broken)

Tags: c, libxml2

i have used libxml2.Here when i am getting an XML data as a string i am unable to check whether it is a valid xml or a broken xml.so can anyone let me know how to check for the validation of xml in c using libxml2 or can suggest any more way to check for the validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/)?

Comment: @Subratnayak if you want to use libxml2 you can have a look at this example: http://knol2share.blogspot.it/2009/05/validate-xml-against-xsd-in-c.html